# How to style only half a sentence

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I was wondering is there a way to style half a sentence for title. Usually I would go about this by using span like so: `<span>Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet.` But this won't work if using CMS like wordpress.

Comment: Are you on the business plan? Because on that you can install plugins that might allow you to do what you're looking for.

Comment: This exact question has been asked before and has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687858/changing-specific-word-in-site-title-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

You still can do that  in Wordpress, just use the "text" mode of the editor, where you can write HTML code and insert spans with classes.

Comment: this won't work for post title

Comment: by default you won't be able to style titles on Wordpress

Comment: @MariaVan Well, you didn't mention "title" in your original question (before editing it), but only "half a sentence", so that's what I was referring to.

Comment: @Johannes sorry